# Is it possible to make a YAML use ISO 8601 date format?

Tags: linux, terminal, yaml

I am using a tool called [`organize`](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize) in order to sort folders with a lot of stuff in them and was wondering if it was possible to tell it to create, sort, or rename using *ISO 8601* date format.

The config file goes like this:

```
rules:
    - folders: *private
      subfolders: true
      filters:
          - extension: pdf
          - created
      actions:
          - echo: "Found PDF!"
          - move: /run/media/[REDACTED]/Documents/unsorted_pdfs/{created.year}{created.month}{created.day}/
```

The folders it creates, are named like this: `201781`; I, however, want them named like this: `20170801`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML itself has no standard date type. The syntax here is purely a `organize` thing. See the ["Advanced Usage" in  section in the README](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize#advanced-usage), where `{created.month:02}` results in `01` for January. So, presumably you need `{created.month:02}{created.day:02}`.

Comment: "Note the format syntax for `{created.month}` to make sure the month is prepended with a zero."... wow. I can't believe I missed that part. Thank you very much!